# FFMPEG video scale & add image background

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, video-processing

I want to create a video with ffmpeg. There are background image(450pxx800px) and video(unknown sizes). I want scale to video 450x800 and put the image video background. I try this code but when finish job, video create without audio. what must i do?

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i C:\Users\drt\Desktop\media\background\bg4.png -vf "movie='C\:\\Users\\drt\\Desktop\\media\\fX4I0jW8_fX4I0jW8.mp4',scale=450:800:force_original_aspect_ratio=1,pad=450:800:0:264:color=black@0,setsar=1[inner];[in][inner] overlay=0:0[out]" -ss 00:00:00.000 -to 00:00:15.000 -y C:\Users\drt\Desktop\media\2q4pyZpSCE7syzJMj.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map the output streams. Also, no need to use the movie filter: that method is from a billion years ago.

```
ffmpeg -y -i C:\Users\drt\Desktop\media\fX4I0jW8_fX4I0jW8.mp4 -i C:\Users\drt\Desktop\media\background\bg4.png  -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=450:800:force_original_aspect_ratio=1,pad=450:800:0:264:color=black@0,setsar=1[inner];[0:v][inner]overlay=0:0[video]" -map "[video]" -map 0:a -c:a copy -to 00:00:15.000 C:\Users\drt\Desktop\media\2q4pyZpSCE7syzJMj.mp4
```

Comment: thank you for correct answer. can we add a  watermark this command line? video, background and water mark... can we do this in same line ?

Comment: @ASPMaker Yes. Just add another input and another ovrelay.